# How to add the post_author into the new post record without having post_author input?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, admin

I'm using active_admin to manage my data. I manage the posts via active_admin, and now I just want to create a new post, so in the new page, I created a form for the post_title、post_content and so on. But I don't want the author to fill the post_author himself, so the problem comes: What should I do when the author click the create button then the author's name or author's id will added to the new post record automatically without having certain input for post_author?

```
form do |f|
  f.inputs "add title and time" do
    f.input :event_title,:label=>"title"
    f.input :event_time, :label=>"time"
  end
  f.inputs "add event" do
    f.input :event_description,:label=>"description"
  end
  f.buttons
end
```

Comment: presumably you're using active admin bundled with devise, in which case you can set your `@post.post_author = current_user` in your controller when saving.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a hidden field that's populated with the current poster's name.

The default, as shown on the Active Admin docs, is:

```
# config/initializers/active_admin.rb
config.current_user_method = :current_admin_user
```

which you need to embed in your hidden form field. Either use a helper method or an instance variable to access the name in the view to populate the form.

Alternatively, you can assign the author after the fact in the #create controller method for a post.

Comment: Thanks for so much.I thought the hidden input can be much easier for me. By the way, I installed the active_admin in the former time, it will install the devise, but there isn't the controller for devise.It seems that if I install the devise again it will have conflict, so it will be hard to modify the #create?